# how to enable intellisense in visual studio code for local python packages

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pylint

I have created a very basic package. Created a folder named my_package with mkdir, created a **init**.py file in this folder, and then created a my_modules.py file in the same folder.

my_modules.py has one function

```
def hello():
    print('Hello')
```

---

I created a python script (a.py) in VS Code, put the following lines in a.py and ran a.py.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/my_package')
from my_package.my_modules import hello
```

And now, even when I launch python3 interpreter, and import sys, and print(sys.path), I see the path to my_package in the sys.path list.

Now, script a.py runs alright and prints hello.

However,

- pylint shows a warning - Unable to resolve 'my_package.my_modules'. IntelliSense may be missing for this module.

Both pylint and intellisense are otherwise working in my VS Code setup. I have tried

- to add init-hook in .pylintrc (that did not help remove the intellisense warning)
- to setup PYTHONPATH variable.

Neither of the above were helpful in removing the intellisense warning.

Btw, when I copied the my_package directory to site-packages directory of my python 3.7 installation, then the warning went away. The copying to site-packages path appears to be a kludge as it will likely break the next time python updates.

What should I do? And I hope my question was clear. Thank you.

Comment: did you check [this](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/troubleshooting_intellisense/)?

Comment: [this](https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/autocomplete/) link from the page worked. will learn venv usage also and then use the venv approach. thank you.